# Fastlane Match and GitHub Actions Can't access certificates repository

Tags: react-native, github-actions, fastlane, fastlane-match

Hi I'm using Fastlane and GitHub actions in a React Native Project.
Here's my steps:

```
cd ios/

fastlane init

fastlane match init

Add url to repository, via https://github.com

fastlane match development
```

All the certificates are installed, but after running the GitHub Actions, this is the error that occurs:

[image]

> Fastfile:

```
default_platform(:ios)
platform :ios do
  desc 'Fetch certificates and provisioning profiles'
  lane :certificates do
    match(app_identifier: 'com.company.app', type: 'development', readonly: true)
    # OR
    match(git_basic_authorization: ENV["MATCH_GIT_BASIC_AUTHORIZATION"])
  end

  desc 'Build the iOS application.'
  lane :build do
    certificates

    gym(scheme: 'App', project: './ios/App.xcworkspace')
  end
end
```

> Matchfile

```
git_url("https://github.com/USERNAME/certificates.git")

storage_mode("git")

type("development")

app_identifier(["com.company.app"])
```

> A Snippet of GitHub Workflow

```
  - name: Run Fastlane
    working-directory: ./ios
    run: bundle exec fastlane ios build
    env:
      MATCH_GIT_BASIC_AUTHORIZATION: ${{ secrets.MATCH_GIT_BASIC_AUTHORIZATION }}
```

The Token is a fine granted token generated for the repository "certificates", and it is encoded to base 64 following the documentation:

```
echo -n your_github_username:<93 chars long token> | base64
```

And then store in the git repository secrets of the app.

If I run the following command in my local machine:

```
git clone https://github.com/USERNAME/weav-certificates.git clone -c http.extraheader='Authorization: Basic <my_token>'
```

it doesn't work because of "http", but with git@... instead it works, verifying that the token is properly set.

So I guess I need to change the match repository url in the configuration, as not shown in the documentation, and after doing it again the same auth problem.

- Then I have set in the Xcode Project to not automatically maange sign-in
- Since I'm using React Native, the project to run is .xcworkspace
- com.company.app is created even in AppStore connect`enter code here`